# How to avoid "TypeError: Input z must be at least a 2x2 array" when trying to generate a contour plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a contour plot of the gravitational potential of a 2 body system. The input is the masses of the 2 bodies and their separation. I keep receiving the error

> TypeError: Input z must be at least a 2x2 array.

which I assume is referring to the PHI term in ax.contour(X,Y,PHI).

I have tried changing the x, y, and phi so that they match (I don't understand why they don't already match because phi is generated from the x and y values). Also, I have never used the contour plot before and I have limited programming experience so please forgive my ignorance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n=100
#x and y evenly spaced values
x=np.arange(-n,n,0.01)
y=np.arange(-n,n,0.01)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
r=np.array([X,Y])
#r is the scalar distance from the center that each test particle resides at
#r=np.array([(X**2+Y**2)**0.5])<--this was used to generate the output image

def Lagrange(m1,m2,a):
    mtot=m1+m2
    #the distance from the bodies to the center of mass of the system
    x1=-(m2/mtot)*a
    x2=(m1/mtot)*a
    omsq=mtot/(a**3) #omega squared term

    def phi(r):#gravitational potential function
        phi= -m1/abs(r-x1)-m2/abs(r-x2)-0.5*omsq*r**2
        return phi

#I also had a vector plot included in this code (among other details), 
#but decided to omit them as it's not relevant to the error I am receiving. 

    fig=plt.figure()
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    PHI=np.meshgrid(phi(r))
    ax.contour(X,Y,PHI) #3rd dimension is the contour lines
    plt.show()

Lagrange(3.0,1.0,1.0)
```

I expect by taking the input x and y coordinates of the system (their lengths match) and using the generated output values from the phi function (which should also match the length of x as well as y) to generate a contour plot, where the contour lines will represent the gravitational potential given by phi.

Here is the pair of images I mentioned in the comments. [python code (left) vs working matlab code (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAyh1.png)

Comment: You got the `X,Y=meshgrid` right, but not the `PHI=meshgrid`.  Test this sort of thing with small cases in an interactive session.  Look at what each operation does.

Comment: I am beyond lost... I got a contour output by omitting PHI completely and instead using phi without the meshgrid, but the output seemed to be rotating. I figured the rotation was due to using r as an array of scalar distances from the center of the system instead of passing the x,y coordinates of each test point with respect to the 2 bodies' x,y coordinates (which lie on the x axis so their ordered pairs would be (x1,0) and (x2,0)). Now nothing is working and I've spent all day trying to fix it. I do appreciate the comment though as It finally led to SOMETHING being generated. Please help me.

Comment: I appended an image to my question which shows what I have generated by not using meshgrid on phi (left) and a working matlab code output (right) which I am trying to emulate in python.

Comment: `x` and `y` are 1d arrays, the `r` calculated from them is also 1d, and so is `phi(r)`.  You could think of it as values along a `x=y` diagonal across your graph.  Why aren't you use `X` and `Y` to calculate `r` and `phi` - values at points on the mesh defined by those arrays?  `phi(r)` should have the same shape as `X`.  In MATLAB as well as numpy, getting the dimensions right is 2/3 of the battle.  Check the dimensions regularly; don't make any assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, I was using X and Y instead of x and y to calculate r in the code that works. I just updated the code in the question to reflect this. I think I may have to resort to utilizing the dot product/cross product/norm so that the function phi handles r correctly.